# Is it possible to add @Override keyword with conditional define (I mean on some API version only)

Tags: java, android, methods, overriding

I want to override the actionmode. However the base class have now starting at API 23+ the public method onWindowFocusChanged. in my code I override like this

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus) {

}
```

but i want also to target api < 23, and in api < 23 if i call MyObject.onWindowFocusChanged i will receive a `E/AndroidRuntime(23165): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.ActionMode.onWindowFocusChanged`

is it possible to say the keyword `@Override` only if api >= 23 and else to omit it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@Override` annotation just hints the compiler to check the parent(s) class(es) for the same signature and helps you avoid assuming a method overrides something when it really doesn't. Once compiled, it does not affect the functionality of that method.

If you indeed to only override this method when using api>=23 (as opposed to not supporting older APIs at all), you should not use this annotation.

Comment: so i can use it without any trouble right ? because in api 23+ it's an abstract method and i m force to override it

Comment: @Henry Yes, you can implement it without the annotation